# How to access a custom field in a PHP Exception object in jQuery's jqXHR object?

Tags: php, jquery

I created a subclass of PHP's Exception class (which I'll call MyException) because I needed to add an additional property that contains a more user-friendly message for the user. So aside from the usual properties of the Exception class (i.e., `$message`, `$code`, ...), I added a property called `$userMessage`. I ran into no problems with this, and it works very well within PHP.

But when I get to the final moment when I throw a MyException within PHP for .`ajax()'s .fail()` handler to receive, how do I access this custom property (i.e., `$userMessage`) from the jqXHR object?

Thanks.

Comment: That depends on the way you manage the exception on php, and the way you make the ajax request. Post some of that code.

Comment: Basically, you should echo the userMessage property. Something like `echo $myExceptionObj->userMessage`

Comment: `console.log()` in javascript and the console of your browser are your best ally in this.